# Python Newbie Combine Text

Tags: python

How would I remove the space after the equals sign? I searched all over google and could not find anything on how to do it. Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

```
Code
    customer = input('Customer Name:')
    mpid = input('MPID=<XXXX>:')
    print ('description' ,customer,'<MPID=',mpid+'>')

Output
    Customer Name:testcustomer

    MPID=<XXXX>:1234

    description testcustomer <MPID= 1234>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ways of combining strings...

```
name = "Joel"
print('hello ' + name)
print('hello {0}'.format(name))
```

So you could use any of these in your case...

```
print('description', customer, '<MPID={0}>'.format(mpid))
print('description {0} <MPID={1}>'.format(customer, mpid))
```

Comment: The `%` string formatting syntax is deprecated in favor of the more powerful `.format()` method and therefore shouldn't be taught any more.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for the notice!  I removed that example.

Comment: @JoelMercado: You're welcome.  Please accept answers when they solve your problem to indicate that your question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('description',customer,'MPID='+str(mpid)+'>')
```

I'd think this is what you'd do.  You've already done that no-space concatenation with the closing angle bracket.

Comment: Edit: Must change mpid to string for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the title is general, I thought this might be helpful to some even though it is not directly related to the full question:

The interpreter combines text strings (but not refences to strings) when they are next to each other on the same line or continued line.

```
>>>'this sen'   "tence w"                  '''ill be combined'''
'this sentence will be combined'
```

This allows line breaks and white space in long strings to improve readability without making the program have to deal with reassembling them.

```
>>>('1
     2
     3
     4')
'1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(a, b, c)` puts `a` into the output stream, then a space, then `b`, then a space, then `c`.

To avoid the space, create a new string and print it. You could:

concatenate strings: `a + b + c`

better: join strings: `''.join(a, b, c)`

even better: format a string: `'description  {0} <MPID={1}>'.format(customer, mpid)`